# Is there a way to standardize table formatting across desktop and mobile clients?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am working on a MS Teams bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework which needs to send results formatted in a table to users through chat. However, every method I have tried to send this formatted table is rendered differently on desktop, IOS, and Android clients. I have tried sending an adaptive card formatted with columns, monospace font in an adaptive card, monospace font in a message, and an xml message with a formatted table. Is there a method that I am missing that will display uniformly across different clients? Or even a way to display a different message payload based on the client?

Comment: Hi @Eric Storey,

The size of Adaptive Cards in the Teams client is determined by the Teams client itself based on the current viewing area width - you cannot directly influence this value.

Answer (score 0):

The size of Adaptive Cards in the Teams client is determined by the Teams client itself based on the current viewing area width - you cannot directly influence this value.